# need assistance Ultragrid (infragistics). cant combine data columns from 2 sources

Tags: vb.net, infragistics, ultrawingrid

i have a project with winform and VB.net.
i got there 2 UltraGrids (infragistics) that each one has its own data source.

its working great but i need to do some changes.

how can i combine a field to the first from the other?

i have tried to change columns with the Ultragrid designer, even though i can see it, it doesn't show.
the first grid gets datasource and the other gets the data from SQL Query.

is it only by code or there is a shortcut?

Comment: there is no way first grid to know anything about the data source of the other grid. If you need to change something in second grid after interaction in the first gird you should handle this yourself by some custom code.

Comment: thanks. i was hoping for some shortcuts.... :)